# Hide UISearchBar background in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios4

The below code to hide background of `UIsearchBar` works fine till iOs4.2 but not in iOS4.3 or later.

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The view hierarchy has probably changed due to the appearance API. Set a breakpoint in `-viewDidLoad` and while the program is paused, type `po [searchBar recursiveDescription]` in the console to get a list of the entire view hierarchy, including private class names.

Comment: @Mark Adams - don't know but creating UIsearchBar programmatically instead by nib worked for me

Comment: If you're executing the code in `-initWithFrame:` then that's obvious. Loading from a nib uses the `-initWithCoder:` initializer.

Comment: @mark - I am executing the code in viewDidLoad.

Comment: In that case `searchBar` was probably nil because it's outlet wasn't connected to the interface builder.

Comment: In my case iOS 5.0.1 I remove the UISearchBarBackground view but I can still see other controls in the background. I believe its the segmented control

Comment: I can confirm that creating the UISearchBar by code, does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no issue for this code ....but also giving you a alternate solution , replace code of for loop to

```
    [[[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 7 another UIView was added to the UISearchBar, here is the solution for iOS 7:

```
UIView *vw = [yourSearchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
for (id img in vw.subviews) {
    if ([img isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [img removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

You could also do the following (also works in iOS 7):

```
[yourSearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
[yourSearchBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but for reference here it is

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        UIImage *image  = nil;
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        if (context) {
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
            image= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.backgroundImage = image;
    });
});
```